# Personal Access Token not working with TFS 2017 Package feed

Tags: tfs, nuget

I have setup TFS 2017 in a VM, create a project and added the package feed extension. I then created a feed and a personal access token with full access.

My problem is that I cannot push a package to the feed from the command line using `nuget.exe` `3.5.0` and a personal access token. I am using the instructions found [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/nuget/auth#personal-access-tokens) and on the feed page (2nd command below)

My commands:

```
nuget.exe sources Add -Name MyFeed -Source "http://server2016:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/MyFeed/nuget/v3/index.json" -Username administrator -Password x7m5hochjcf4vabp3zqeekrzi7mtbyk6at5tujdt2ny5fgienlgq
nuget.exe push -Source "MyFeed" -ApiKey VSTS C:\temp\octopack.3.4.6.nupkg
nuget.exe list -Source MyFeed
```

The output I get for both `push` and `list`:

```
Using credentials from config. UserName: administrator
Please provide credentials for: http://server2016:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/MyFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
UserName:
```

I tried entering the username and PAT again, but it just prompted me again.

If I use my Windows credentials (same account as the PAT) it works fine. I checked with Fiddler and the auth challenge is getting sent and responded to. The server returns a 401.

Any idea why TFS isn't accepting the PAT?

Answer (score 4):

As of nuget 5.0, you have access to set "ValidAuthenticationTypes".  See `nuget sources -?`

```
 -ValidAuthenticationTypes             Comma-separated list of valid authentication types for this source. By default,
                                       all authentication types are valid. Example: basic,negotiate
```

This controls a new key in your nuget.config

```
<add key="ValidAuthenticationTypes" value="basic" />
```

Which prevents nuget from attempting Negotiate/NTLM/Kerberos auth against your local TFS/AzureDevOps Server.

#### Some History

The problem here is usually Negotiate getting in the way.  Nuget (and tools built on the underlying libs like 'msbuild /restore' or 'dotnet') is good at making auth simple when you are logged in and AD can negotiate NTLM/Kerberos for you.  Unfortunately when configuring Basic creds it can try to pass these off during negotiate, which fails.  It is worth noting this was only a problem with the local Server instances and not the azure.dev.com/visualstudio.com cloud hosted instances since Negotiate wouldn't trigger in the cloud scenarios.

This was addressed in part under credentialProvider plugin flows, which could return an auth type for its creds, and if a specific environment variable were set nuget would disable UseDefaultCredentials and skip negotiate (this was used in Azure Pipelines for nuget auth for TFS/AzureDevops Server).

It got a final fix in nuget 5.0 with https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/pull/2297, which lets you set the auth type even in config files, when manually specifying PATs/passwords for basic auth.  As of now, nuget docs are still [pending](https://github.com/NuGet/learn.microsoft.com-nuget/issues/1283).

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce your issue if use `nuget.exe 3.5.0` and a personal access token. But there is no issue if you use **nuget.exe 3.4.3** and a personal access token in TFS 2017.

[image]

Please get the `nuget.exe 3.4.3` from Nuget page directly instead of using `nuget.exe 3.5.0`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking into that. However this was just the tip of the iceberg. We are actually using the NuGet client libraries and need 3.5.0 for it's SemVer support.

Comment: I also just noticed in your screen shot that you configured a v3 feed, but the push command ends up using a v2 feed

Comment: @RobertWagner, I didn't set anything, just download the Nuget, copy and paste the commands from the site. As from the test, TFS 2017 supports PAT, You may try to get help from Nuget side to see whether they can help you.

Comment: When I said configured, I meant added. The url for the `source add` and `push` commands is different

Comment: @RobertWagner I can reproduce this issue with nugget 3.5 too. Since you need to use 3.5, you need to use windows account (username and password) instead, otherwise you need to use 3.4.3.

Comment: Try entering `. ` as user or `pat` instead of your username.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to add the `-StorePasswordInClearText` option to the `nuget.exe sources Add` command.

Comment: And it's a pretty insecure practice. Really a last resort thing.